# writing address book by using class in python

Tags: python

I has a problem about the address book.
Here are some information about the question:

**The address book allows to query friends of friends (like LinkedIn does with connections): a friend of degree 1 is a direct friend, a friend of degree 2 is a friend of a friend**

I try to solve this problem,but i still have not idea to solve the last steps.

Here is my code:

```
class AddressBook:
    def __init__(self):
        """Creates empty address book"""
        self.book = {}
    def addName(self, name, address):
        """Adds name to address book, with address and
        no friends"""
        self.book[name] = address
    def addFriend(self, name, friend):
        """Adds friend to the set of friends of name"""
        self.book[name] = friend
    def address(self, name):
        """Returns the address of name"""
        n=set()
        for e in self.book:
            if self.book[e] == name:
                n.add(e)
        return n
    def friends(self, name, degree):
        """Returns the set of all friends up to the specified
        degree"""
        n=set()
        for name in self.book:
            if self.book[name] == degree:
                n.add(name)
        return n
```

Here are some correct output:

```
    >>>a = AddressBook()
    >>>a.addName('Ann', 34); a.addName('Bill', 62); a.addName('Barb', 95)
    >>>a.addName('Emma', 56); a.addName('Fred', 46); a.addName('Jane', 90)
    >>>a.addName('Joe', 33); a.addName('Lisa', 21); a.addName('Lucy', 18)
    >>>a.addName('Mary', 52); a.addName('Sue', 12)
    # Transitivity
    # Fred -> Barb -> Jane -> Emma -> Lisa
    # Fred -> Sue
    #                 Jane -> Mary
    >>>a.addFriend('Fred', 'Barb'); a.addFriend('Fred', 'Sue')
    >>>a.addFriend('Barb', 'Jane'); a.addFriend('Jane', 'Emma')
    >>>a.addFriend('Jane', 'Mary'); a.addFriend('Emma', 'Lisa')
    >>> a.friends('Fred', 0)
    set()
    >>> a.friends('Fred', 1)
    {'Barb', 'Sue'}
    >>> a.friends('Fred', 2)
    {'Barb', 'Jane', 'Sue'}
    >>> a.friends('Fred', 3)
    {'Mary', 'Barb', 'Jane', 'Sue', 'Emma'}
    >>> a.friends('Fred', 4)
    {'Barb', 'Emma', 'Mary', 'Lisa', 'Sue', 'Jane'}
```

But,My output is all `set()`

Can you guy give me some feedback and hints to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem, you want friends to be returned as strings rather than as a set ??

Comment: Consider an address book that, besides addresses, keeps track
of someone’s friends.

Comment: I do not understand how the following three statements work togather `self.book[name] = friend`,  `self.book[e] == name` and `self.book[name] == degree`

Comment: I also don't understand what "the problem" is. You are trying to make a social network, but you are only building the graph one link at a time. I don't see how the transivity is established